# How can I post item on business page using facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook

I successfully share items on my own profile using the api

```
function share(url) {
    FB.ui({
        method : 'share',
        href : url,
    }, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
        } else {
            //alert('Error while posting.');
        }
    });
}
```

but how can I post the same item on my business page using the api ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

Comment: post it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post on a page *as* the page via API, then you have to get permissions from a page admin first, and get a page access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens